# Can i re-order these divs without changing the HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have an eCommerce platform that has their Product Images displayed in the DOM before the products title and description. I don't have access to changing their HTML, but i wanted to know if there was a way to re-order these elements with CSS?

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="img">Img</div> 
  <div id="Content">
     <div id="title">
       Title
     </div>
     <div id="description">
       Description
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make the #content to be above the #img, but sadly with no luck.

Here is a demo.

[Demo Link Here](http://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/bpLvLr)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use flexbox to do this:

```css
div {
  margin:2px;
}
#wrapper {
  background-color:red;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  -ms-flex-direction:column;
  -webkit-flex-direction:column;
  flex-direction:column;
}
#img {
  background-color:blue;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  -ms-flex-order:2;
  -webkit-order:2;
  order:2;  
}
#title {
  background-color:yellow;   
}
#description {
  background-color:green;
}
#Content {
  -ms-flex-order:1;
  -webkit-order:1;
  order:1;  
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="img">Img</div> 
  <div id="Content">
    <div id="title">Title</div>
    <div id="description">Description</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just wanted to mention that if this is for mobile and/or trying to get best cross-browser support then -webkit- and -ms- prefixes are required for flexbox. Just a note.

Comment: @KyleHawk - added browser specific prefixes

Comment: Ended up using this method. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of different ways you can do this. Sebastian already talked about flex box. If you make the wrapper div `position:relative`, then any child elements with `position:absolute` will be moved in that element absolutely (instead of the page). This was super quick, but you can always change the numbers to make it more appealing.

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
}
#img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 10px;
}
#title {
  left: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 0;
}
#description {
  top: 15px;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="img">Img</div>
  <div id="Content">
    <div id="title">
      Title
    </div>
    <div id="description">
      Description
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Side Note##

I would change from using `id=...` for all of these to `class=...` if you plan to have more than one copy of these. ID's are meant to be unique, classes are repeatable.

```css
    .wrapper {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 50px;
    }
    .img {
      position: absolute;
      right: 5px;
      top: 10px;
    }
    .title {
      left: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      top: 0;
    }
    .description {
      top: 15px;
      left: 0;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img">Img</div>
  <div class="Content">
    <div class="title">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Description
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img">Img</div>
  <div class="Content">
    <div class="title">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Description
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well other than those colors being murder ( I know why you did it), yeah you could do that with flex boxes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS table + table caption.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7v8ec0wn/)**

```css
#wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#content {
  display: table-caption; 
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="img">Img</div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="title">
      Title
    </div>
    <div id="description">
      Description
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, use flexbox and set it to reversed column.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8syndkdd/)**

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="img">Img</div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="title">
      Title
    </div>
    <div id="description">
      Description
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```